# Find $y$ in $\sqrt{4+(y-6)^2}+\sqrt{16+(y-3)^2}=3\cdot\sqrt{5}$

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, optimization, analytic-geometry, radicals

I would like to solve this equation for $y$. Any tips? It seems like you cant really do it analytically?

> $$\sqrt{4+(y-6)^2}+\sqrt{16+(y-3)^2}=3\cdot\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: @Allawonder where are you getting a quartic?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt My bad. My judgement was quite premature. I later saw that terms higher than the square vanished, as explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider points $A(2,6)$, $B(-4,3)$ and a point $P(0,y)$ on y-axis. Then notice that given equation is actually $$AP+BP= AB$$ so $P$ is (by triangle inequality ) on a line $AB$ so it is an intersection point of the line $AB$: $$ y= {1\over 2}x+5$$ and $y$-axis, so $y=5$.

Comment: woow very fancy

Answer (score 3):

Set $y-3=z,$ then square both sides and simplify to get $$z^2-3z-8=-\sqrt{4+(z-3)^2}\sqrt{16+z^2}.$$ Squaring again and simplifying the right hand side gives $$(z^2-3z-8)^2=(z^2-6z+13)(16+z^2).$$ Now let $16+z^2=w,$ then expand and simplify to get $$z^2+16z+64=5w.$$ Substituting back for $w,$ simplifying and factoring gives the quadratic $$(z-2)^2=0.$$ Thus, $z=y-3=2,$ so that if there is a solution, then it has to be $y=5.$ Substituting this in the original equation assures us that this is indeed the only solution.

Comment: What does suggest $\sqrt{\dfrac{4+(y-6)^2}{5}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{16+(y-3)^2}{5}}=3$? It is clear that $y=5$ is a root.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: After squaring one times we get
$$2\sqrt{4+(y-6)^2}\sqrt{16+(y-3)^2}=25-(y-6)^2-(y-3)^2$$
squaring again and simplfying we get
$$4 \left(46 y^2-450 y+975\right)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

You can factor out $2$ at the second summand.

$$\sqrt{\underbrace{4+(y-6)^2}_{=5}}+2\cdot \sqrt{\underbrace{4+\left(\frac{y-3}2\right)^2}_{=5}}=\sqrt{5}+2\cdot\sqrt{5}$$

Now we see that  the following equations has to be true at the same time.

1. $(y-6)^2=1 \Rightarrow y_1=7,y_2=5$
2. $\left(\frac{y-3}2\right)^2=1\Rightarrow y_1=5,y_2=1$

Thus the solution is $y=...$